# Bootstrap Accordion Trouble

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to learn bootstrap. I took the code from the bootstrap docs for the 'Flush' Accordion but mine just looks completely wrong. I don't understand why. I've linked the CSS stylesheet and the JS Bundle. [This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbmoO.png)

I haven't tampered with the default code at all. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code: (the accordion is at the very bottom)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Learning Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark py-2 fixed-top">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">&lcub; &rcub;</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navmenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#courses" class="nav-link">Courses</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section class="bg-white text-light p-5 p-lg-0" id="home">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="text-center text-sm-start">
                    <h1 class="text-dark">Become a <span class="text-primary">Web Developer</span></h1>
                    <p class="lead text-dark">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste labore voluptatum nisi non error
                        impedit alias ullam. Sint numquam quae minus quam, aut rem, sed officiis inventore consectetur
                        eveniet veniam.
                    </p>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Start Now</button>
                </div>
                <img src="/images/home.jpg" class="img-fluid w-50 d-none d-md-inline-block" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="bg-dark text-light p-5">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="d-md flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <h3 class="mb-3 mb-md-0 pb-2">Sign Up For Our Newsletter</h3>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" aria-label="Enter email"
                        aria-describedby="button-subscribe">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button-subscribe">Subscribe</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="pt-5" id="courses">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="card bg-dark text-light p-3">
                            <div class="h1 mb-3">
                                <i class="bi bi-laptop"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="card-title mb-3">Virtual</h3>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
                                asperiores
                                tempora itaque delectus quod quasi.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="card bg-dark text-light p-3">
                            <div class="h1 mb-3">
                                <i class="bi bi-person-square"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="card-title mb-3">Hybird</h3>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
                                asperiores
                                tempora itaque delectus quod quasi.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md">
                        <div class="card bg-dark text-light p-3">
                            <div class="h1 mb-3">
                                <i class="bi bi-people"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="card-title mb-3">In-Person</h3>
                            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor
                                asperiores
                                tempora itaque delectus quod quasi.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="col-md">
                    <img src="/images/learn.jpg" alt="Learn image" class="img-fluid w-100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md p-5">
                    <h2>Learn The Fundamentals</h2>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed autem
                        quibusdam alias
                        magnam molestias facere.</p>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta, culpa libero.
                        Libero, sunt nam.
                        Vel voluptatum accusamus cupiditate dolore, distinctio, sapiente perspiciatis harum nihil
                        expedita repellat amet inventore non deleniti?</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="bg-dark">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between text-light">
                <div class="col-md p-5">
                    <h2>Build Projects</h2>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed autem
                        quibusdam alias
                        magnam molestias facere.</p>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta, culpa libero.
                        Libero, sunt nam.
                        Vel voluptatum accusamus cupiditate dolore, distinctio, sapiente perspiciatis harum nihil
                        expedita repellat amet inventore non deleniti?</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">
                        <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i> Read More</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md">
                    <!-- <img src="" alt="Learn image" class="img-fluid w-100"> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
            <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
                            Accordion Item #1
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne"
                        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to
                            demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the first item's accordion
                            body.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#flush-collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseTwo">
                            Accordion Item #2
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="flush-collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingTwo"
                        data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to
                            demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the second item's accordion
                            body. Let's imagine this being filled with some actual content.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
                        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                            data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
                            Accordion Item #3
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="flush-collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse"
                        aria-labelledby="flush-headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
                        <div class="accordion-body">Placeholder content for this accordion, which is intended to
                            demonstrate the <code>.accordion-flush</code> class. This is the third item's accordion
                            body. Nothing more exciting happening here in terms of content, but just filling up the
                            space to make it look, at least at first glance, a bit more representative of how this would
                            look in a real-world application.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you add the `bootstrap.css` in html?

Comment: Yes i did, which is why I'm very confused

Comment: pls share your code

Comment: I've shared! Sorry for the delay, new to stackoverflow, had to take a minute to figure it out. Thank you guys for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have bootstrap@4.0.0 in your link and in the script below you have bootstrap@5.1.3

Replace your link at the top with this one

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

That should make work your Accordion

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be the CSS link but I didn't think to check the version. Works perfectly